# Conversion of an alcohol to a methyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols

I'm only interested in the first conversion: D to E.

I've been thinking about this for a little bit. My first thought was to use $\ce{TsCl}$ to make a good leaving group then a $\ce{Me}$ nucleophile. This didn't seem like it would work since $\ce{Li-Me/MeMgBr}$ would just displace the leaving group. My second thought was to convert the alcohol to a halide, make it a Grignard reagent, then react it with $\ce{MeBr}$. But that also wouldn't work. Any suggestions?

[image: Question]

Comment: Consider going via ketone.

Comment: You might also consider an organocuprate as a nucleophile. Ordinarily, I wouldn't suggest a secondary electrophile for SN2, but this is also benzylic so...

Comment: I considered ketone, that would add the methyl easily using Me-Li then an OH would be left. Add TsCl then a weak reducing agent, NaB(CN)H3, but would that work to remove the OH?

Comment: Oxidise to ketone, Wittig, then hydrogenate

Comment: @MalcolmHall It should, but there is a more reliable way. The resulting alcohol should dehydrate really easy. In fact, it might dehydrate during acidic treatment of Grignard reagent adduct.

Comment: Ionic hydrogenation with Et3SiH/TFA will reduce the benzylic OH very easily

Answer (score 5):

As [@orthocresol](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16683/orthocresol) mentions in the comments, the better way to undertake this synthesis would be to first oxide the alcohol to a ketone, perform the Wittig reaction and than hydrogenate the product.

[image: OH to CH3]

Another possible reaction sequence might be first convert the alcohol into a ketone, use a Grignard reagent and than reduce the alcohol.

[image: OH to CH3]